# Automatically refer to n-th author

Tags: labels, sorting, author

I'm writing a paper with many people, and to be honest, at this point I'm not even sure who will be listed as an author in the final version. In the text, I would like to write things like "the forty-second author conjectured" but without knowing '42' in advance (okay, I must admit that in reality we are not that many).

> Is there a way to label the authors to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a pure LaTeX solution, but if you use R,  with `knitr` there are an easy way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
<<theverylonglistofauthors,echo=F>>=
authors <- c(
"Davy Jones ",
"Hannibal Lecter",
"Norman Bates",
"Freddy Krueger",
"Jack Torrance", 
"Darth Vader",
"James Moriarty"
)
@
\title{We are legion}
\author{\Sexpr{combine_words(authors[1:3], sep=" \\and ", and="")}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

Forensic analysis of \Sexpr{authors[2]} about legacy of commercial transcantions
of \Sexpr{authors[1]} showed  that he is as guiltless as the mam of 
\Sexpr{authors[3]}. 
All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. 
All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.
All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.

\section{Acknowledgements}

We would like to thank to \Sexpr{combine_words(authors[5])} the  help 
to write the present document with the guidance of 
\Sexpr{combine_words(authors[c(4,6)])}.

Back luck, \Sexpr{combine_words(authors[7])}, you are out! 

\end{document}
```

> [image: mwe]

Comment: LOL, amazing answer!

Comment: @Fran +1 just for the text... Lol...